# How Can I Save A Boolean In NSDefaults When A Button Is Pressed?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've coded a night and day button theme. If the user presses the day button, `GlobalData.DayBool = true`, and `GlobalData.NightBool = false`. When they press the night button, `GlobalData.DayBool = false` and `GlobalData.NightBool = true`. The background changes to night or white, depending on which one is true and false.

Let's say that the user clicks the Night Button. `GlobalData.NightBool = true`, and `GlobalData.DayBool = false`, and the background changes to black.

I want the booleans to be saved depending on which button they press, so that when they close the app, their background will be the same as they had selected.

```
//Day Button Pressed
for touch: AnyObject in touches {

    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if dayButton.containsPoint(location) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            _ = touch.locationInNode(self)

            backgroundColor = GlobalData.dayColor
            GlobalData.nightBool = false
            GlobalData.dayBool = true
        }
    }
}

//Night Button Pressed
for touch: AnyObject in touches 
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if nightButton.containsPoint(location) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            _ = touch.locationInNode(self)

            backgroundColor = GlobalData.nightColor
            GlobalData.nightBool = true
            GlobalData.dayBool = false 
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code for when it switches backgrounds depending whether one of them is true or false:

```
//Day Background
if GlobalData.dayBool == true && GlobalData.nightBool == false {
    backgroundColor = GlobalData.dayColor
}

//Night Background
if GlobalData.nightBool == true && GlobalData.dayBool == false {
    backgroundColor = GlobalData.nightColor
}
```

Please leave any questions below if you have any. I really need help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `IBAction` for your button and do the NSUserDefault section below.

## [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

I always like to register my NSUserDeafult to default setting,  a lot of people just continue with the second step without registering.

**Register NSUserDefault in AppDelgate.swift**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["valueName": AnyObject])
```

**Set Value** to your NSUserDefault, this depends on what type of data you're storing, should match the one with your registration if you did register. (Example of Boolean data type below)

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "valueName") //Bool Data Type
```

Make sure you synchronize once you set the value to the NSUserDefault, this way it will update instantly, otherwise it will update when it get a chance.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Receive Value:** this will receive boolean value since we set boolean and register boolean.

```
let Variable: Bool! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("valueName")
```

Comment: So do I have to create a variable for GlobalData.nightBool and GlobalData.dayBool

Comment: And what do I put for the valueName

Comment: If you want or use it by itself, cause you want to check it to see what the value and change the background accordingly, correct?

Comment: for `valueName` anything that match what you doing and what you want to receive.

Comment: to save int, bool, float, etc to defaults use `NSNumber.init(bool:SomeValue)` and to read, `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("somekey").boolValue`

Comment: The main purpose of registering a default value is to provide one for the key: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["valueName": false])`, then you have specified both the type and a default value.

Comment: I'm using spritekit @FarhadNežad so where should I register it? Just anywhere in the AppDelegate?

Comment: @JoshSchlabach **AppDelegate.swift** is my favorite place for this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: @Lucho: `valueForKey` is inappropriate. Use the designated methods `boolForKey: / setBool:forKey:` instead. Swift bridges `Bool` to `NSNumber` automatically

Comment: I just put the register line of code you gave me in it and it says "Value of type AnyObjects.protocol does not conform to expected dictionary value of value type "AnyObject @FarhadNežad

Comment: @JoshSchlabach On which line? please speak in code :)

Comment: I put                   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["valueName": AnyObject])   in AppDelegates in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function

Comment: Well remove it for now, Try without registering. otherwise specify your data type.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing this wrong but it's not working. Can you help me in private chat?

Comment: @JoshSchlabach yes let do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98433/discussion-between-josh-schlabach-and-farhad-nezad).

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate / `applicationDidFinishLaunching` register the key/value pairs, assuming `day` is `true` by default and `night` is `false`.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["day" : true, "night" : false]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

Then read the values wherever you want (but always after registering them):

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
GlobalData.dayBool = defaults.boolForKey("day")
GlobalData.nightBool = defaults.boolForKey("night")
```

Consider that there are no optionals at all!

Save the values as well wherever you like (preferable in `applicationWillTerminate)`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(GlobalData.dayBool, forKey("day")
defaults.setBool(GlobalData.nightBool, forKey("night")
defaults.synchronize()
```

The `synchronize` line can be omitted.

As `day` seems to be always the opposite of `night`, one default key might be sufficient.

Comment: Nice one, you can also use `GlobalData.dayBool` as the value for boolean. Good point vadian. I will up vote this :)

Comment: @FarhadNežad you don't have time to help me on something related to this NSUserDefaults right now do you?

Answer (score 0):

update for Swift 5:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self?.email, forKey: "email")
UserDefaults.standard.set(self?.password, forKey: "password")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadysignedup")
```

retrieve

```
if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "alreadysignedup")){
            if let email1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email") {
                
                self.emaildefault = email1
                
                if let password1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password") {
                    
                    self.passworddefault = password1
                    signIn()
                }
            }
        }
```

I am aware that you should not user sensitive data to store in UserDefaults (use Keychain for that), but this is just an example.