# Saving and retrieving a bool with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a *bool* value to UserDefaults from a UISwitch, and retrieve it in another view. However, I've tried following multiple tutorials and stack answers and none seem to work.

This is how I'm saving it:

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var soundSwitchOutlet: UISwitch!

@IBAction func soundSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(soundSwitchOutlet.isOn, forKey: "sound")

}
```

and this is how I'm trying to retrieve it in another view:

```
if let savedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound") {
        boolValue = savedValue
    }

//this is inside viewDidLoad and "boolValue" was declared outside viewDidLoad//
```

For a reason this code is giving me errors and none of the things I've tried have worked. How can I save a bool to UserDefaults and retrieve it in another view?

Edit: I think I fixed the first part. However, the way I'm retrieving the boolean seems to be totally wrong. Also: No other stackExchange answer responds to what I'm asking, at least not in swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373668/how-can-i-save-a-boolean-in-nsdefaults-when-a-button-is-pressed ?

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "sound")`

Comment: reading bool for key returns a Bool (not optional) `boolValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As Leo mentioned in the comments `bool(forKey` returns a non-optional `Bool`. If the key does not exist `false` is returned.

So it's simply

```
boolValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")
```

Calling `synchronize()` as suggested in other answers is not needed. The framework updates the user defaults database periodically.

Comment: Thanks! The state of the switch is staying saved, but when I try to use the bool value on another view, it gets stuck on the boolean value it began with.

Comment: Don't misuse `UserDefaults` as temporary storage or to pass data between controllers.

Answer (score 3):

**Do it like this.**

In your `first view controller`.

- create an `IBoutlet` connection to your `UISwitch`
- And then the action for your `UISwitch`. so in the end, your `first view controller` should look like this.

import UIKit

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myswitch: UISwitch! // Outlet connection to your UISwitch (just control+ drag  it to your controller)




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func myswitchAction(_ sender: Any) { // Action for your UISwitch

        var myswitctBool : Bool = false // create a local variable that holds your bool value. assume that in the beginning your switch is offed and the boolean value is `false`

        if myswitch.isOn == true { // when user turn it on then set the value to `true`
            myswitctBool = true
        }
        else { // else set the value to false
            myswitctBool = false
        }


        // finally set the value to user default like this
        UserDefaults.standard.set(myswitctBool, forKey: "mySwitch")
        //UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() - this is not necessary with iOS 8 and later.


    }

}
```

> End of the first view controller

**Now in your second view controller**

- you can get the value of `userdefault`, which you set in `first view controller`. I put it in the `viewdidload` method to show you how it works.

import UIKit

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            let myswitchBoolValuefromFirstVc : Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mySwitch")// this is how you retrieve the bool value


            // to see the value, just print those with conditions. you can use those for your things.
            if myswitchBoolValuefromFirstVc == true {
                print("true")
            }
            else {
                print("false")
            }


        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }




    }
```

**Hope this will help to you. good luck**

Comment: yep @EricAya we do not need it anymore from iOS 8. accepted and I will remove it. thanx

Answer (score 2):

Use this line of code:

```
@IBAction func soundSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(soundSwitchOutlet.isOn, forKey: "sound")
}
```

insteadof :

```
@IBAction func soundSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(soundSwitchOutlet, forKey: "sound")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func soundSwitchs(_ sender: Any) 
{
    UserDefaults.standard.set(soundSwitchOutlet.isOn, forKey: "sound")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() 
}

  //this is inside viewDidLoad and "boolValue" was declared outside viewDidLoad//

 boolValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")
```

Comment: `.synchronize()` is useless. Run tests, you'll see by yourself.